# margin: 0 auto; not working in IE also everything disarranges. UL also disarranges

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, margin

I am getting lots of trouble with IE. The whole page is disarranged even though I have reset applied to all the tags initially. Mozilla and Chrome displays it correctly but IE is giving lots of tension. If anyone could help I would be very thankful.

Jquery is also not working fine. and div are disarranged

First see it in mozilla to get a look of what I have designed. then open it in IE to see the troubles.

See it here [http://www.crawller.com/opal/](http://www.crawller.com/opal)

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone.
I solved the problem by including this line at starting before

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This solved the problem and CSS and jquery codes are responding well in IE now.
You can check the modified version at 
http://www.crawller.com/opal/new/

The old one is also available at http://www.crawller.com/opal/

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it appears there are some incorrectly spelled attributes in your css, several references to 'bloc' where I assume you mean 'block'.

Make sure that your html and css validate.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of Markup validation errors in your document. First try to fix those errors.

[Check your site for w3c Markup Validation](http://validator.w3.org/)